# Toggle only 1 submenu on li ng-click and not allow another li to open

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-animate

I have a working menu after reading the docs and examples & implementing it with basic ngAnimate - css3 transition but I really don't know how to go about it so bear with me.

1. how to toggle only 1 li submenu at a time & not let the other one open because it's overflowing
2. onclick (anywhere if possible) outside of that menu / submenu close the active submenu
3. my css3 ngAnimate is animating the li elements that don't have subitems, how do i check that and give it the toggle class only if it has subitems?

Here is my html code for menu & i'm using ng-repeat to repeat li & it's submenu from my controller -

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <div class="" layout="column">
    <li md-ink-ripple="#ebeef4"
        ng-repeat="item in items"
        class="item {{item.id}}"
        ng-click="states.activeItem=item.title;
                  itemClicked = !itemClicked">
      <span>
        <i class="material-icons md-24 center-icons">{{item.icon}}</i>
      </span>
      <a class="title" ng-href="#!{{item.route}}">{{item.title}}</a>
      <span>
        <i class="material-icons md-18 subicon-openstate" id="test-icons">{{item.subicon}}</i>
      </span>
      <ul class="submenu" id="submenu-item-hover" ng-if="itemClicked">
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.subItems" class="subItem">
          <a href="#!{{subItem.subroute}}">{{subItem.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

you can see i'm using ng-if on the submenu i.e. 2nd ul to check if it's clicked and when it returns true it uses this css code -

```css
#submenu-item-hover.ng-enter {
  transition: all ease-in 0.3s;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#submenu-item-hover.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  height: 144px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#submenu-item-hover.ng-leave {
  height: 144px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#submenu-item-hover.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  transition: all ease-in 0.3s;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

But the problem is it opens/closes fine if i click on only 1 of the li with subitems but when i click on the 2nd one that also opens causing overflow vertically(sidenav)
And if i click on the li which has no submenu that also opens to 144px height :s
so how do i go about it?. Also lastly how to write onclick (outside menu function) to toggle(close) the active submenu.

edit- adding controller file too

controller -

```js
app.controller('NavigationController', function($scope) {
  $scope.states = {};
  $scope.states.activeItem = '';
  $scope.items = [{
    id: 'item1',
    title: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'dashboard',
    subicon: 'arrow_drop_down',
    route: 'dashboard',
    subItems: [{
        title: 'Page Visitors',
        subroute: 'page-visitors',
      },
      {
        title: 'Post Performace',
        subroute: 'post-performance',
      },
      {
        title: 'Team Overall',
        // subroute: '/team-overall',
      }
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'item2',
    title: 'Calendar',
    icon: 'calendar_today',
  }, {
    id: 'item3',
    title: 'Inbox',
    icon: 'inbox',
    subicon: 'unfold_more',
    subItems: [{
        title: 'New Mail',
        // subroute: '/new-mail',

      },
      {
        title: 'Scoial',
        // subroute: '/new-social',
      },
      {
        title: 'Updates',
        // subroute: '/new-updates',
      }
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'item4',
    title: 'Invoicing',
    icon: 'insert_drive_file',
  }, {
    id: 'item5',
    title: 'Lab / Experimental',
    icon: 'build',
  }];
});
```

Comment: thank you for editing it. if this question is already answered, could anyone please link me to the post related topic. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you share your working example on the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

You are sharing the itemClicked var across all `<li>`'s which is causing them all to open. I suggest leveraging your activeItem variable you are already setting. For example:

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <div class="" layout="column">
    <li md-ink-ripple="#ebeef4"
        ng-repeat="item in items"
        class="item {{item.id}}"
        ng-click="states.activeItem=item.title">
      <span>
        <i class="material-icons md-24 center-icons">{{item.icon}}</i>
      </span>
      <a class="title" ng-href="#!{{item.route}}">{{item.title}}</a>
      <span>
        <i class="material-icons md-18 subicon-openstate" id="test-icons">{{item.subicon}}</i>
      </span>
      <ul class="submenu" id="submenu-item-hover" ng-if="states.activeItem === item.title">
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.subItems" class="subItem">
          <a href="#!{{subItem.subroute}}">{{subItem.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Furthermore I would set a function for you ng-click so you can do a little more logic around if you want the click to register or not based on if there are sub-items. For example

```html
<li md-ink-ripple="#ebeef4"
        ng-repeat="item in items"
        class="item {{item.id}}"
        ng-click="toggleSubNav(item)">
```

```js
$scope.toggleSubNav(item) {
  if (item.subItems) {
    $scope.states.activeItem = item.title;
  }
}
```

Comment: I modified your code with some of my use case. i needed to show the active li(main) title on my view so i was using that states.activeItem to show the active li string. what i did - added $scope.itemClicked = $scope.clicked = !$scope.clicked; inside the func and swapped the$scope.states.activeItem = item.title to the ng-click and with your ng-if i added && operator to check if it "itemClicked" so only the li with title will show if it's clicked or not and also only drop if has subitem. And it works perfectly with slide down/up! thank you for your explanation & time taken to help me out!

Comment: oops i think i made a mistake. my li with no subitem is breifly expanding because i'm not checking if the clicked/!clicked is on a li with subItem or not how do i write the ng-if to check if all 3 are true? i.e has subItem, is clicked and has the active title. i tried like ng-if="toggleSubNav(item)  && states.activeItem === item.title " since my subitem checking and item clicked checking is done in the same function this code does't toggle anything but the active title works fine because it is separately defined.

Comment: sorry it got fixed i added the 3rd condition which is && item.subItems on ng-if and it fixed the bug of opening of no subItem li. sorry for bothering you. But thanks again for all the help